# Error in OK button selection listener in a SWT/JFace Dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I am receiving the below exception while trying to access the field value from a text field within a SWT Dialog, from the selection listener of the 'OK' button.

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
```

I can understand the error is because the Dialog is already disposed when I am trying to access it. But i haven't made any explicit call to dispose the shell.

Is the Dialog disposed automatically on clicking the 'OK' button? Is there any way it can be overridden? Or Am i doing something wrong here?

Appreciate any help or pointers. Relevant code snippet below:

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {

    /** The file Name Text field. */
    private Text fileNameText;

    /** The constructor. **/
    protected MyDialog(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell);
    }

    /** Create Dialog View. **/
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite mainComposite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);

        fileNameText = new Text(mainComposite, SWT.BORDER);
        fileNameText.setText("");
        fileNameText.setBounds(0, 20, 428, 20);

        return mainComposite;
    }

    /** Override method to set name and listener for 'OK' button. **/
    protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
        super.createButtonsForButtonBar(parent);

        Button submitButton = getButton(IDialogConstants.OK_ID);
        submitButton.setText("Review");
        setButtonLayoutData(submitButton);

        // Perform Selected CleanUp activity on Submit Click.
        submitButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                // do something.
                if (fileNameText.getText().isEmpty()) {
                        return;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the dialog is automatically disposed when the OK button is clicked and No you should not stop this.

What you must do is override `okPressed` and save the text value before the dialog is disposed:

```
private String fileNameValue;

....

@Override
protected void okPressed()
{
  fileNameValue = fileNameText.getText();

  super.okPressed();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. that worked. Only issue is that, the view has a number of inputs and all these need to be assigned to variables before calling the `okPressed` method.

Comment: Yes, it can get messy. You could use [JFace data binding](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataBinding/article.html) to automatically set fields in a class.

Comment: Thanks.. I will have a look on the same.